# Miun through a telephone/teleconference

Tags: halacha, technology, divorce, minor-katan-child, even-haezer

According to Halacha, If a minor girl gets married to a man, if she shows intellectual capability over 6, she has to do Miun instead of a Get. Miun is her expression of refusal to the marriage. My question is, can Miun be expressed through a telephone or teleconference? Is this similar to getting someone else to write a Get via teleconference  which according to [this article](https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/the-use-of-a-videoteleconference-for-a-get-procedure-by-rabbi-chaim-jachter) some Poskim permit?

Comment: You mean to the witnesses?

Comment: @shmosel does miun need witnesses?

Comment: This is a cool question but extremely unlikely to have been dealt with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miun is not contemporaneously practiced. Accordingly, the question of modern communication devices and their impact on this practice does not practically arise and remains unaddressed by contemporary Poseqim.

Here is a relevant section from [AH EH 155](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Even_HaEzer.155.49?lang=bi&lookup=%D7%94%D7%92%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9F&with=Lexicon&lang2=en) on the topic:

> כתב רבינו הרמ"א בספרו דרכי משה ס"ס זה כתב מהר"ם מריזבור"ק שלא למאן
> בזמה"ז כלל אפילו אינה בת י"ב שנים חדא שלא יתחלף בא"א דעלמא ותו שלא תבא
> למאן בפני ג' עמי הארץ וכן הוא בתשו' מהר"ם פדוו"א סי' י"ג בשם מהר"י
> מינ"ץ והאריך עוד הרבה להראות פנים להחמיר בזמה"ז אמנם מהר"י פול"ק עשה
> מעשה בימיו והתיר אשה שמיאנה בימיו וחלקו עליו כל גדולי אשכנז ויצא הדבר
> בהיתר ונשאת לאיש אחר בלא גט עכ"ל ועפ"ז כתב בש"ע ס"ס זה וז"ל ולכ"ע אם
> היא פחותה מבת יב"ש ממאנת אפילו בזמה"ז וכן עשה מהר"י פול"ק מעשה בימיו
> ודלא כיש מחמירין ואמרו שאין בת ממאנת בזמה"ז כלל עכ"ל וצ"ע שהקיל בזה
> והמהרש"ל ז"ל כתב ביש"ש פי"ג דיבמות סי' י"ז וז"ל נהגו בימים האחרונים
> אשר לפנינו שלא למאן ונתפשטו מהחכם מוהר"ר מנחם מעיל צדק וכו' והסכימו
> לזה כל החכמים האחרונים גדולי הדור אשר היו לפנינו ובפרט הגדול והחסיד
> מהר"י מרגליות ומהר"פ מפראג ומהר"י מינ"ץ וכו' וגדול אחד בדורו אשר היה
> לפני נהג ועשה הלכה למעשה והושיב ב"ד ומיאנה יתומה בבעלה ונחלקו עליו
> וכו' והיתה נשאת אותה אשה לאדם אחר ע"פ המיאון אבל שמעתי שזיוגן לא היה
> עולה יפה לכן מסכים אני לגזירת הקדמונים שלא למאן ואף אם מיאנה שלא
> להשגיח במיאון ולאסור אותה עד שתתגרש אבל אם נשאת וכו' עכ"ל וגם רבינו
> הרמ"א עצמו בסעיף א' כתב דלכתחלה יש לב"ד ליזהר שלא להשיא יתומה קטנה
> במקום שנראה להם שיבא לידי מיאון ואין לדין בזה אלא מה שעיניו רואות עכ"ל
> כלומר שאם נראה שלא תבא לידי מיאון ישיאנה ולהדיא אמרו חז"ל ביבמות
> (ק"ט.) לעולם ידבק אדם בשלשה דברים ויתרחק משלשה דברים ידבק בחליצה
> ובהבאת שלום בין אדם לחבירו ובהפרת נדרים ויתרחק מן הפקדונות ומן
> הערבונות ומן המיאונין ומפרש הטעם שמא תתגדל ותתחרט ע"ש וכתבו שם התוס'
> פיר"ח בשם גאון דאין לקדש יתומה עד שיביאו ראיה שהיא בוגרת כדי להתרחק מן
> המיאונין והא דתקינו לה רבנן נשואין צ"ל לדברי הגאון דהיינו דווקא היכא
> שיש לחוש שלא ינהגו בה מנהג הפקר עכ"ל הרי דגם רבותינו בעלי התוס'
> והגאונים חשו שלא למאן וגם בימי חורפי שמעתי שבדור שלפנינו היה איזה
> מיאון והרעישו חכמי הדור את העולם ולא ידעתי מה עלתה בזה ועתה בזמנינו לא
> נראה ולא נשמע הדבר הזה כלל וכלל כי לבד זה אין מקדשין אצלינו קטנות וגם
> ע"פ דינא דמלכותא כן הוא:

(I'll try to come back and translate or paraphrase the most relevant parts later) And so in Ashkenaz, miun (with very rare exception) was unseen  past the 16th century.

Among Yemenite Jews the practice persisted until a later age than most other communities. However they mostly lived in very poor communities without electricity (let alone telephones) and shortly after most of the community came to Israel ([Operation Magic Carpet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Magic_Carpet_(Yemen))) the practice came to a full halt as the Israeli rabbinate enacted a series of rulings concerning marriage 1950 ([see here](https://www.daat.ac.il/daat/ezrachut/harabanut2a-2.htm)). Accordingly even in the one community in which this question could possibly even have remotely been considered, it was still a non-sequitur.

Comment: Isn't this more of a comment than an answer?

Comment: @N.T. it answers the question "can Miun be expressed through a telephone or teleconference?" The answer is "no, it cannot be expressed through a telephone because it cannot be expressed at all. Here's why..."

Comment: You're just saying the question isn't relevant. You didn't answer the underlying question, which might be theoretical, but is still a question.

Comment: @N.T. see here: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2179/i-know-a-and-based-on-a-im-asking-b

And the question isn't framed as a theoretical, it therefore isn't being answered as one.

Comment: Occasionally you hear of teenagers getting married and having to get divorced. I can imagine a 13 year old boy whose intellectual education outpaces his emotional development marrying off his sister to his friend.

Comment: @Heshy and were that case to arise, the contemporary rabbinic answer is never to utilize miun.

Comment: @Deuteronomy what would they do instead? Leave her married? Write a get?

Comment: Most likely explore the totality of circumstance in depth and attempt do demonstrate that she was never meqadesh in the first place.

Comment: @Deuteronomy what if they can't find a way to demonstrate that?  And then let's say the husband dies and he has a brother with no legs?  I think miun would be chosen over leaving her as an agunah.

Comment: @Heshy if such a far fetched situation ever arises and is addressed I'll be just as curious as you to learn about how.